# MySQL Workbench -> not enough privileges to view Client Connections

Tags: mysql, permissions, mysql-workbench

I set a MySQL workbench and when I try to access the tab with Client Connections it shows the message:

**The account you are currently using does not have sufficient privileges to view the client connections**

[image: MySQL Workbench Client Connections error]

But If I use the terminal and execute a `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` it resolves correctly.
I am missing some MySQL Workbench configuration?

Answer (score 0):

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON databasename.* TO 'username'@'localhost';
```

please try this query